# How to model an old curved tv screen?

Tags: modeling

I try to model an old tv.
Now I have a hard time to recreate the curved screen. 
I tried inverting and extruding the area and then applying a sub surf modifier, but that does not work.

Then I had the idea to distort the plane twice via a simple deform modifier but that is also not the right solution in my opinion:

[image: Simple deform modifier]

Also proportional editing is not really working:
[image: Proportional editing]

How would you solve it?
This is the TV (screen) I’m going for:

[image: Pic1]

[image: Pic2]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- ad Plane, Subdivide, Modifier-Cast>Sphere controled by Empty to get base curvature of glass

[image]

- ad another Plane as TV-glass, Modifier-Cast>Sphere to set oval sides from front view, Modifier-ShrinkWrap to get base curvature of first Plane, Select edge loop and Extrude it in Y axis (to avoid shrinking this extrude create Vertex group of front faces and assign it to modifier)

[image]

- select extruded faces, duplicate, separate ... and you have a frame, ad solidify modifier ... TV box as ussual :)

[image]

Note: 
- use Subdivison Modifier as much as you need
- thanks to modifiers you can adjust front and side shape any time to make it more or less sphery :)

[image]

Comment: Thank you for these steps!

Comment: I somehow missed this answer before, but it really helped me now :). I really like the procedural approach.

Answer (score 3):

It's the default NURBS surface scaled. Just add it, connect vertices with edges and fill the inside. Extrude the rectangle made of edges. Solidify and bevel the extruded sides to make the black rim.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but unfortunately I cannot really follow you.

Comment: Hello :). Could you please add some images to illustrate? It's a very good idea just a bit hard to follow.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you try a very low-poly object with *Subdivision Surface* modifier?

[image]

or

[image]

Comment: This is a soap bar.

Comment: the shape might be wrong, but I meant you only need several faces to make it   ;)