# Image textures 'wiggling' when the mesh moves?

Tags: animation, mesh, armature

I'm making a short animated video in blender, and I have a model of a TV with an image texture on the screen. When the TV moves, the image texture does not move very smoothly, and wiggles.

[here is a shot from the video demonstrating this.](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1EotJo2oQ1RGKiVTqz8P4rr3eqojNa86A/view?usp=sharing)

EDIT: [image: a screenshot of the shader, as requested]

EDIT2: [image: Updated Shader]
[Rendering with updated shader](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1d-X2h7Z5pX6uM13--Omd9vIJulLqPAxR/view?usp=sharing)

Edit3: .blend file of just the tv [image]

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of the shader controlling the texture in the question so we can have some more info to help?

Comment: Agreed. There is not enough information in the video to properly help with this issue. It would be great to have some screenshots of the node setup, and possibly the mesh or modifiers.
Do you have any sort of displacement on this object? Or possibly several planes layered which would cause the textures to fight?

Comment: @Nascent Space I have added a screenshot of the shader, though it isn't much more than a simple image texture.

Comment: I would guess it's because you have a Surface and a Volume shader. Volume calculations might have subtle differences each frame? Don't know for sure. Try removing the Volume input. If you intended to mix the two emission nodes, feed them into a mix shader node and put that into Surface.

Comment: @hatinacat2000 I tried adding a mix shader node, as well as removing the emission node entirely and using a simple image texture, but the problem persists. I'll link a screenshot of the shader as well as a short test rendering in the main post.

Comment: @vklidu If you look at the node setup I am using there is no displacement modifier. I am using an armature. I will attach a blend file so you can check out the problem yourself. It appears that it definitely has something to do with the armature, as when I tried moving the object without the armature the texture moved normally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### ISSUE

Problem is TV screen topology (not Material or assigned Armature). Screen is ngon that doesnt have enough geometry in surface.
You have curved edges, but there is not an information how to model surface. So blender generates some :)

In viewport it looks flat ...

[image]

... but for rendering are ngons triangulated. What Happens with surface when rendered you can see when in edit mode search for *Triangulate Faces*

[image]

### QUICK FIX

Simplify corners, delete screen face, select border with active vertex (white) in corner
[image]

and search for **Grid Fill**, set **Span** to 16 in my case.
[image]

To make screen edge sharp after *Shade Smooth*, select it and search for **Mark Sharp**
[image]

Easy check surface with some Matcap view type
[image]

[image]

Or you can try to model screen like [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/159738/2214).